# Object string is printing to HTML stream in Rails 4.1

Tags: html, ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a couple of simple polymorphic relations in Rails (4.1).  The Address and Phone objects can belong to either a Person or an Organization object.  All of the plumbing appears to work correctly - the CRUD operations are all working as they should and all my tests pass.
The show action for both Person and Organization includes a partial that is supposed to display the related Addresses and Phones.  While those fields do display correctly, the entire Ruby object also renders as a string in the HTML stream, and that is of course problematic.
The show action of the PeopleController:

```
def show
    @addressable = @person
    @addresses = @addressable.addresses

    @phoneable - @person
    @phones = @phoneable.phones
end
```

The @person variable is set in a before_action using a private function:

```
def set_person
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
end
```

The show.html.erb for person (just the address and phone section):

```
<h3>Addresses</h3>
<%= render 'addresses/addresses' %.
<br>
<h3>Phones</h3>
<%= render 'phones/phones' %>
```

The _address.html.erb partial (the phone one is essentially identical):

```
<%= @addresses.each do |address| %>
  <%= address.address_line_1 %><br>
  <%= address.address_line_2 %><br>
  <%= address.address_line_3 %><br>
  <%= address.address_line_4 %><br>
  <%= address.city + ', ' + address.postal_code %><br><br>
<% end %>
```

The HTML output is this (again, this is just the address and phone portion):

```
<h3>Addresses</h3>

  1 Viceroy Plaza<br>
  Suite 1300<br>
  Office 125<br>
  <br>
  Toronto, C8R 9G3<br><br>

  1313 Mockingbird Lane<br>
  Apt. 227<br>
  <br>
  <br>
  Mississauga, H3V 8Y4<br><br>
[#&lt;Address id: 2, address_line_1: &quot;1 Viceroy Plaza&quot;, address_line_2: &quot;Suite 1300&quot;, address_line_3: &quot;Office 125&quot;, address_line_4: nil, city: &quot;Toronto&quot;, postal_code: &quot;C8R 9G3&quot;, verified: false, use_for_contact: true, picture_file_name: nil, addressable_id: 1, addressable_type: &quot;Person&quot;, created_at: &quot;2014-04-13 20:32:41&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2014-04-13 20:32:41&quot;&gt;, #&lt;Address id: 1, address_line_1: &quot;1313 Mockingbird Lane&quot;, address_line_2: &quot;Apt. 227&quot;, address_line_3: nil, address_line_4: nil, city: &quot;Mississauga&quot;, postal_code: &quot;H3V 8Y4&quot;, verified: false, use_for_contact: true, picture_file_name: nil, addressable_id: 1, addressable_type: &quot;Person&quot;, created_at: &quot;2014-04-13 20:18:56&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2014-04-13 20:18:56&quot;&gt;]
  </br>
  <h3>Phones</h3>

  (1) 416-3219700<br><br>

  (1) 289-4346789<br><br>
[#&lt;Phone id: 2, country_code: &quot;1&quot;, area_code: &quot;416&quot;, phone_number: &quot;3219700&quot;, phone_extension: &quot;13125&quot;, verified: nil, use_for_contact: nil, phoneable_id: 1, phoneable_type: &quot;Person&quot;, created_at: &quot;2014-04-13 20:34:54&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2014-04-13 20:34:54&quot;&gt;, #&lt;Phone id: 1, country_code: &quot;1&quot;, area_code: &quot;289&quot;, phone_number: &quot;4346789&quot;, phone_extension: nil, verified: nil, use_for_contact: nil, phoneable_id: 1, phoneable_type: &quot;Person&quot;, created_at: &quot;2014-04-13 20:30:54&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2014-04-13 20:30:54&quot;&gt;]
```

As you can see, the actual objects are rendered in the stream as well as the desired HTML.
Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`each` returns the thing you're calling `each` on so:

```
@addresses.each { ... } == @addresses
```

And `<%= ... %>` is for interpolation so this:

```
<%= @addresses.each do |address| %>
```

puts `@addresses` in the HTML and that's where the odd looking HTML is coming from.

You just want to say `<% ... %>` with `each`:

```
<% @addresses.each do |address| %>
```

to *evaluate* (not *interpolate*) the `each`.

Comment: Thank you for the catch.  I stared at the code so long, I completely missed the obvious!